# Bones rotate outside of mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

So when i rotate the bones sometimes it leaves the mesh instead of staying inside.
any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: in Weight Paint mode, make sure that your bone weigh on your mesh

Comment: I Checked weight paint, it looks pretty good. the mesh moves with the bone but hardly.

Comment: Another bone must influence this part of the mesh so you should remive it from any group then assign it to this bone again